# Using Recursion to find sum of applicable integers

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to take an integer (X) and use recursion to find the sum of digits that apply to a particular condition up to X. For example, given 10 and using conditions divisible by 2 or 3, the sum would be 5.

I have already used a different loops to solve the problem and now trying to practice with recursion.

```c
       int sum(int n) {
           int totalSum;
           if (n==0)
            return 0;
           else {
               if ((n%2==0)||(n%3==0)){
                   totalSum+= sum(n-1);
                   return totalSum;
               }
               else {
                totalSum=sum(n-1);
                return totalSum;
               }
           }
        }
```

I keep either receiving a zero or an incredibly high number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your problem, you will have to extract a [mcve] that illustrates what exactly doesn't work as expected, along with a description of the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
totalSum+= sum(n-1);
```

can't possibly be correct. You never initialized `totalSum`, so how could it be correct to add something to it? Even if C automatically initialized variables, it would presumably initialize it to `0`, so this would be equivalent to `totalSum = sum(n-1);`, which is the same thing you do when `n` is *not* a multiple of `2` or `3`.

Notice that neither of your conditions adds the current iteration variable to anything. You should be adding `n`, not `totalSum`:

```
totalSum = n + sum(n-1);
```

Comment: That was definitely what I was doing incorrectly. I was forgetting to add the iteration variable. Thank you!

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answer. Readers need to see what the original problem was so they understand the answer.